# How to perform data binding of WPF/XAML using PowerShell

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I have several PowerShell modules I've developed using WPF/XAML and one of them uses an example I found and used to bind a DataGrid ItemSource property to a variable called "resultsData":

`<DataGrid Name="gridResults" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource resultsData}"/>`

Then in the Window.Resources section of my XAML file there is a reference made to the data binding value:

`<Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="resultsData" Type="sys:Object"/>
</Window.Resources>`

Finally, in PowerShell I can update the DataGrid's property as follows:

`$uiHash.Window.Resources["resultsData"] = $uiHash.resultsHash`

This works really well and I'm trying to replicate it in another project where I'm simply trying to bind the text property of a TextBlock using the Windows.Resources section in my XAML file. The problem is I have no idea what to put in that section to make it work.

I've tried using the same `<x:Array>` tag but it's obviously not an array. I've tried `<x:Code>` and `<x:Null>` and a multitude of other options which all result in a failure to load the window along with Visual Studio's visual designer barfing...

Could someone help me understand what to put in the Windows.Resources section to ensure I can reference these properties in PowerShell through the Window.Resources object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Text` property of a `TextBlock` can be set to or bind to a `string` which is defined like this in XAML:

```
<sys:String x:Key="textResource">some text...</sys:String>
```

...where `sys` is mapped to the `System` namespace:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```